# iPhone 3 cannot login with existing Apple ID

Tags: iphone, apple-id

Phone: iPhone 3 or iPhone 3GS
iOS: 6.1.6

I tried to login to App Store , iCloud and iTunes with an existing Apple ID, it shows the below alert:

[image]

I’ve done that multi factor login from my MacBook to iPad and vice versa. But on my iPhone it does not work. It doesn’t give me an option to type in the 6 digit verification code. What should I do? I don’t mind resetting it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Have you reset it already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enter:

```
[Your Password][Your Verification Code]
```

into the password field (without the brackets).

For example, if my password was `TerriblePassword` and my verification code was `123456`, I would enter:

```
TerriblePassword123456
```

Source: [Apple's Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204915) (Thanks @redarm!)

Comment: I am curious to learn if this behaviour is documented anywhere?

Comment: I know I've seen it on Apple's website before, but I don't have the page atm. But also, if you read the message in OP's screenshot, it's actually giving you the above instructions—but they're terse to the point of being a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: What if I use two-factor authentication on a device running older software?
If you use two-factor authentication with devices running older OS versions—like an Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation)—you might be asked to add your six-digit verification code to the end of your password when signing in. Get your verification code from a trusted device running iOS 9 and later or OS X El Capitan and later, or have it sent to your trusted phone number. Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204915